# Random User Id in MobileFirst 7.1 Test Token Endpoint

Tags: java, authentication, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to implement integration tests for Mobile First adapters. All adapters use user identity from my custom realm. When writing tests for adapters, I need to know the user id, so that I can prepare some data in database and prepare mocked services.

The problem is that test token endpoint always generates random user id. And it seems there is no way to configure it to provide same user id for each request. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Hey - this is not possible in the current 7.1 implementation. 
The only obvious workaround I can think of is that you make your test independent of the user identity.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is no way to change this in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1, as Ore mentioned in the comments, perhaps you should return the same mock data irregardless of the user identity.